# How to create a flashable ZIP from FlashTools backup?

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, side-loading

I have [this backup](https://mega.nz/#!tYh1AZpL!Lf9pn-U_NkGHjCV6K4cSt37Px8pZISUNGNGVJGoCIa4) that I presume was created using [FlashTools](https://www.needrom.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Pack-Flashtool-v5.1528.00.000.rar) from a stock [MINT 140](http://mundomint.com/mint-140/).

[image]

How can I create a flashable ZIP from that backup, that I can later flash to the device with

```
$ adb sideload rom.zip
```

I know I can flash the individual images with `fastboot` but I'd prefer something I can flash in a single operation.

Comment: Why not just flash them with Flashtool? ROM need to be signed to be able to flash using adb sideload.

Comment: @esQmo_ I have a Mac, I think FlashTools is only for Windows... hmm... I think I'll have to borrow a PC then.

Comment: I think there is a Mac version too... @Izzy has it listed somewhere. Just make a search with tag Flashtool

Comment: @esQmo_ I've found [this](http://www.flashtool.net/downloads.php) but it's a different tool, I think it's only for a particular model of Sony Xperia. Also found [this one](https://spflashtool.com), which appears to be the same tool used to made the backup but it's only Windows and Linux. I'm going to google for some of Izzy's post to see what I can find, thanks.

Comment: The first is Sony Flashtool. What you need is SP Falshtool for Mediatek devices which is on the second link.