# How to extract a system image made with FlashTools?

Tags: stock-android, flashtool, factory-image

I have a system image made with FlashTools. The image and tool are available [here](https://www.needrom.com/download/mint-140/)

Since I have a Mac I can't run FlashTools, also what I need to extract is just an apk that I accidentally deleted from my device.

Can the system.img file be extracted from a Mac?

Comment: [first hit on Google](http://newandroidbook.com/tools/imgtool.html) does it help?

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје I tried `imgtool` and `simg2img` but none can read the file format.

Comment: Ok, stupid question did you unzip archive first? Also in which format is this ROM when you download, I can't see link unless I register (won't happen)

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје Yes, the contents are shown [here in this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/177764/how-to-create-a-flashable-zip-from-flashtools-backup). I tried both tools with `system.img` and also tried renaming the file to `system.img.zip` to see if I could unzip it, but  then result file is also compressed in some other format.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје trying with the raw `system.img` gave the error "bad magic" and unrecognized format with `simg2img` and  `imgtool`